# Remove empty line between source code and results block in org babel automatically

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Is there a variable in org I can use to specify the number of empty lines before the results block; it defaults to 1, but I want to set it to 0.

Comment: No such variable. The insertion of the newline is hard-coded in the function [org-babel-where-is-src-block-result](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/ob-core.el#n2182)

Comment: Ah, OK. Thank you very much for answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that the newline is hard-coded, you can still remove it by advising `org-babel--insert-results-keyword`:

```
(defun my-remove-line (_a _b)
  (save-excursion 
    (previous-line)
    (beginning-of-line)
    (when (looking-at-p "\n")
      (kill-line))))

(advice-add 'org-babel--insert-results-keyword :before #'my-remove-line)
```

This might break things elsewhere though. If it does, maybe you can adjust the advice to prevent that, or you can remove the advice again using `(advice-remove 'org-babel--insert-results-keyword #'my-remove-line)`.